# How can I add date to this code?-after the title of the post--> (Wordpress System)

Tags: wordpress-theming

```
body {
    font-family:"tahoma", "tahoma", "tahoma", tahoma;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:normal;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #1B2F3A;
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/body_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
h1 {
    font-family: "Tahoma", Tahoma, Tahoma;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #1B2F3A;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
h3 span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #003300;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 940px;
}


#top_menu {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#pages {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#pages ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#pages li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#pages a {
    color: #9CBDCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pages a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#search {
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/bgr-search.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
#search input{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #a3a192;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 0 10px;
    width: 178px;
    padding:2px;
}
#search .btn{
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #D3E7F0;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.blog-search {width:100px;}

#header {
    color:#D3E7F0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/moon-300x100.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#D3E7F0;
}
#header a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#categories {
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;
    text-align: right;
}
#categories ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 800px;
}
#categories a {
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1B2E3C;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, Tahoma, Tahoma;
}
#categories li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#categories li li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 150px;
}

#categories li li a, #categories li li a:link, #categories li li a:visited {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #476674;
    display: block;
}

#categories li li a:hover, #categories li li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#categories li ul {
    right: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 10em;
}

#categories li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    right: auto;
}

#categories a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#categories li:hover ul, #categories li.sfhover ul {
    right: auto;
}

#rss{
    right:0px;
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.cat {width: 890px;}


#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}#content {
    background-color: #eaf3f7;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 610px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.post {
    width: 100%;
}



.post h2 a,.post h2 a:visited, .post h3 a,.post h3 a:visited {
    color:#1B2F3A;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.post h2 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.post h3 a,.post h3 a:visited {
    color:#476C7F;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.post h3 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.post h3, #content h3 {
    color:#000000;
}
.post p a,.post p a:visited {
    color:#1B2F3A;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.post p a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.post_details {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.post_details a {
    color: #1B2F3A;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.post_details a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.post_data {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #666666;
    width: 480px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.post_comments {
    text-align: right;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-image: url(http://images/comments_icon.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
.post p img {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 5px;
}
.post p {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.more {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #1B2F3A;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-color: #8BABB8;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.more a {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tags {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #1B2F3A;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/tags1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right ;
    text-indent: 25px;
}
.tags a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tags a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read_more {
    text-align: right;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


#comments-list {
    color:#000000;
}
#comments-list a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#comments-list img {
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
#comments-list li {
    background-color: #E2EFF5;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #F7FBFD;
    border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.comment-meta {
    color:#666666;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.comment-meta a {
    color:#1B2F3A;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.comment-meta a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.avatar {
    float: right;
    padding: 2px;
}


.pagination {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.pagination a, .pagination a:visited {
    color:#006600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.pagination a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav {
    width: 82px;
    height: 21px;
    color:#006600;
}   
.nav a, .nav a:visited {
    color:#006600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #EAF3F7;
    width: 280px !important;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    width: 93%;
    background-color: #03080C;
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/box1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Tahoma, Tahoma, Tahoma;
}
.box a, .box a:visited {
    color:#9ABBCA;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.box a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.box ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    }
.boxline {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #243440;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 5px;
}
.box_title {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
}



#footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #666666;
}
#footer a, #footer a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.previous{
    height:19px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 18px;
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image: url(http://images/prev.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
.next{
    height:19px;
    padding:0px 18px 0px 35px;
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image: url(http://images/next.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
*html .next{
    height:18px;
    text-align:right;
}
.previous a, .previous a:visited, .next a, .next a:visited{
    color:#666666;
}
.previous a:hover, .next a:hover{
    color:#5283C0;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.previous:hover{
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/prev_on.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
.next:hover{
    background-image: url(http://auroraa.webloghaa.com/files/next_on.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}




.meta_entry {
    width:98%;
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.meta_entry a, #meta_entry a:visited {
    color:#CFE3EC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.meta_entry a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navigation a {
    background-color: #1B2F3A;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation a:hover {
    background-color: #03080C;
}
.wp-caption {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding-top: 4px;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.wp-caption img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 none;
}

.wp-caption-dd {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 0 4px 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
blockquote {
border-right:2px dotted #1B2F3A;
background:#eef3f8;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-right:20px;
padding:10px;
}

blockquote p {
margin:0;
}

a.download:link {
    font-family: Tahoma, Tahoma,Tahoma, Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #F9FEFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(http://images/download_bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
}
a.download:hover {
    background-position: 0px -50px;
    color: #D9EAF2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#related {
    width: 600px;
    clear: both;
}
#related ol {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#related p {
    height: 40px;
    width: 645px!important;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    right: -25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    background-image: url(http://images/related_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    margin: 0;
}
#related li a {
    color: #1B2F3A;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#related li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#flickrrss img {
    margin: 3px;    
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted is, not very well represented, CSS and therefore you cannot add any html to it. You need to learn some basics before you go any further.

Comment: What do you mean?? I just need to add date.

Comment: What on earth does "add date" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting here. You probably want Miscellaneous > Time/Date functions, half way down the page on the left hand side.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

**EDIT**

If you want the date and time of the current post then use `the_time();`. You will need to add some parameters to this in order to get the correct time and date format. Have a look here for some examples http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time, and have a look here for a complete list of all parameters to use for date/time formatting http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided is only the CSS which controls the way your blog looks. To add **functionality** like dates you'll need to modify the wordpress template. Here are some resources to get you going in the right direction:

- Learn the basics of wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress#WordPress_for_Beginners
- Learn how to modify wordpress
  templates:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates
- Format date and time:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time